# app is closing by pressing a button in android studio

Tags: android

Here is the error:

> Android resource compilation failed values_values.arsc.flat: error:
>   failed to open.
>       D:\schooldb\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:
>   error: file failed to compile.

Here is the code:

```
protected void validate(String editTextname,String editTextpassword){
   if((editTextname.equals("Admin")) && (editTextpassword.equals("1234"))){
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, option.class));
```

When I am pressing the login button the app is closing. I don't know why.

Comment: See [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 0):

In your Android studio go to RES>values.xml in that you have to add the missing value in it and link that to your android main xml file.